# Segregate Odd and Even elements in an Array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

Given an array of integers in java.

```
int arr[] = {12, 34, 45, 9, 8, 90, 3};
```

Output should be : 
12 34 8 90 45 9 3

There is one catch here. I know how to segregate the even and odd elements but in one of the interviews, I have asked to write a code that will not only do this segregation but also maintain the order in such a way that an even element should follow insertion order with respect to other even elements in array and same for odd elements.

Normal even odd segregation will result [12 34 90 8 9 45 3] but I want the final output as  [12 34 8 90 45 9 3].

For normal even odd segregation I followed this approach:

```
class TestOutput {
static void segregateEvenOdd(int input[]) {
    int left = 0, right = input.length - 1;
    while (left < right) {
        while (input[left] % 2 == 0 && left < right)
            left++;
        while (input[right] % 2 == 1 && left < right)
            right--;
        if (left < right) {
            int temp = input[left];
            input[left] = input[right];
            input[right] = temp;
            left++;
            right--;
        }
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int input[] = { 12, 34, 45, 9, 8, 90, 3 };
    segregateEvenOdd(input);
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++)
        System.out.print(input[i] + " ");
}
```

}

Comment: Why is your strange order 'normal' in any way?

Comment: Could you show your code where you can show you at least tried to resolve the question?

Comment: @pvg - Order is that all the even number should appear in the same order as they are inserted and all the even numbers should appear in the same order as they inserted.

Comment: @AntonH - I followed the same approach as give in below link  [link] (http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/segregate-even-and-odd-numbers/)

Comment: I asked you why you're describing this order ' [12 34 90 8 9 45 3] ' as 'normal'. But either way, include the implementations in your question.

Comment: Giving the link to a site with the code is just saying you did nothing yourself. Did you actually understand the code? Do you at least have an idea of how to modify it to get your intended result? What did **you** actually do beyond copy/pasting code?

Comment: @AntonH -- Sir I tried the same thing but could not able to figure out desired output with O[n] complexity. Refer the code in edited section now.

Comment: It seems rather trivial to make keep the *time* complexity linear, as long as you don't mind linear space complexity, if you build up a new array, count the number of evens, start adding odds to "evensNum" index in `result` array, add evens starting at `0` index...

Comment: @rajvineet Okay, the code you posted is **the code from the website**, which was not written by you (as it says: `/*This code is contributed by Devesh Agrawal*/`). What code have **you** done, **you personally**, to resolve your question?

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
 * Created by maciej.brzozowski.83@gmail.com on 2017-03-30.
 * stackOverflow_43127404
 */
public class ArraySort {

    public ArraySort() {
    }

    public int[] sort(int[] array){
        int[] result = new int[array.length];
        int resultIndex=0; //

        for (int i = 0; i <array.length ; i++) {
            if (array[i]%2==0){
                result[resultIndex]= array[i];
                resultIndex++;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i <array.length ; i++) {
            if (array[i]%2==1){
                result[resultIndex]= array[i];
                resultIndex++;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

}
```

It should do what you need. Code needs two passes throuht array so it needs O(2n) for execute. Under is test for this algorithm in Spock Framework (groovy)

```
import org.junit.Assert
import spock.lang.Specification

/**
 * Created by maciej.brzozowski.83@gmail.com on 2017-03-30.
 * stackOverflow_43127404
 */
class arraySortSpectTest extends Specification {


   def "ShouldSortArrayInSpecificOrderPolishFlagSortOddEven"() {
      given:
      int[] testArray = [12,34,45,9,8,90,3];
      int[] expectedArray = [12,34,8,90,45,9,3];
      ArraySort polishFlagSort = new ArraySort();

      when:
      int[] actualResult = polishFlagSort.sort(testArray);

      then:

      Assert.assertArrayEquals(expectedArray, actualResult);
   }
}
```

Comment: Great Thanks a lot for the answer.